# .ashx images not showing in clean sitecore xpress installation

Tags: sitecore, ashx, sitecore6

I have just installed a clean version of sitecore xpress and upon loading the website, no images are showing. When I login to the desktop or content editor or previewer, all images still fail to show.

The only images that do show are the one or two png's on the login page, which leads me to believe the website is failing to retrieve any .ashx files. I have looked everywhere and I can't find an answer to why these aren't loading.

My setup is on Windows Server 2008 using the latest Sitecore Xpress (as of May 10th 2011) with SQLLite. I have not edited any files, I have just simply installed it.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What happens when you go directly to the ashx images? What kind of error do you get? Permissions or 404, or other?

Comment: @Mark , I get a 404 error. An example URL is: http://website/~/media/Images/Banners/open%20space.ashx if it helps in any way

Comment: I wonder if this post can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742779/sitecore-images-ashx-extensions-not-being-picked-up-by-iis-5-1-or-iis7-express

Comment: I did check that post this morning but to no avail, but thanks anyway. I have no clue what could be happening

Comment: Could it be IIS configuration? Are you using IIS 7 or 6?

Comment: Have you published the images? Obvious question, but it's stumped me sometimes.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. It must have been down to IIS for some reason, marto. I installed it on a version of Windows with IIS 7 and everything is working perfectly now. Thanks too Francis but it wasn't image publishing.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that ashx is not an allowed extension, check your Web.config at:

```
<configuration>
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <preprocessRequest>
        <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.PreprocessRequest.FilterUrlExtensions, Sitecore.Kernel">
          <param desc="Allowed extensions (comma separated)">aspx, ashx, asmx</param>
        ..
      ..
```

Confirm that ashx is an allowed extension.  Another thing you can try is setting the  Media.RequestExtension to a blank value, this allows images to load in their normal extension.

```
<setting name="Media.RequestExtension" value=""/>
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, I see that the issue was related to IIS. I saw from the IIS, the Static Content was not installed. So, it failed to load the images like icons and others. After installing that it fixed the issues.

To solve this issue, please follow the following steps:

1. Go to Server Manager -> Roles -> Web Server
2. Look for the Role Services Box
3. Check if “Static Content” is installed.
4. If it is not installed, click the “Add Role Services” link on the right and add this service.

Hope, it will solve that broken icons and images problem.  :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One more thing to try- check if ashx is handled in IIS